# my fedora PATH variables went out, how to restore them

Tags: linux, environment-variables, fedora

I wanted to add php to envirmonment variables

So I wrote:

export PATH=/opt/lampp/bin/

Then I discovered that this was wrong because it relaced the envirmonment variable PATH  with only ( /opt/lampp/bin/ ).

Is there a way to restore the path to an earlier version?

Comment: `export PATH=/opt/lampp/bin/` is a temporary path. Will work only until you exit the terminal ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restart your shell / exit your terminal. unless you edit your .bashrc file the changes to environment variable via the export command are not permanent